# Revtex warning with bibtex

Tags: bibtex, revtex

I get a warning every time I run bibtex on files using revtex4-1.  I realize that this is just a warning and could be ignored, but my automatic compilation scheme (emacs) complains that there's a warning every time, so I'd really like to get rid of it.  The warning is

```
Warning--jnrlst (dependency: not reversed) set 1
```

This even happens with files revtex supplies as examples, but I've cut it down to a (nearly) minimal working example:  `SimpleTex.tex` is

```
\documentclass[aps,prd,10pt]{revtex4-1}
\begin{document}
Refer to Ref.~\cite{ArticleKey}.
%\bibliographystyle{apsrev4-1}
\bibliography{SimpleBib}
\end{document}
```

and `SimpleBib.bib` is

```
@Article{ArticleKey,
  title =    {Cited work},
  journal =  "Awesomeness",
  author =   {Annie Author},
  year =     1999
}
```

Then, `latex SimpleTex` followed by `bibtex SimpleTex` gives me the warning.  Interestingly, it appears to be using `apsrev4-1.bst`.  But by explicitly giving the bibliographystyle (uncommenting the line in `SimpleTex.tex`), the warning goes away.

Is it safe to just use the `\bibliographystyle` statement?  Any idea why that appears to work?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As of late 2019 [(REVTeX 4.2c)](https://journals.aps.org/revtex), this is still an issue.  I still find that the only reasonable solution is to add `\bibliographystyle{apsrev4-2}`
before the `\bibliography` command.

In general the `\bibliographystyle` given should match the style REVTeX would use according to the class options: `apsrev4-2` (default, most `aps`), `apsrmp4-2` (`aps,rmp`), `aipnum4-2` (`aip` numeric styles), `aipauth4-2` (`aip` author-year styles), `aapmrev4-2` (`aapm`).

The REVTeX-selected `.bst` can also be checked in the BibTeX log:

> ```
> This is BibTeX, Version 0.99d (TeX Live 2022)
> Capacity: max_strings=200000, hash_size=200000, hash_prime=170003
> The top-level auxiliary file: output.aux
> The style file: apsrev4-2.bst
> ```

Comment: Short, sweet and easy answer.

Comment: But one problem is that this may change the bibliography formatting.

Comment: For Physics of Fluids, `\bibliographystyle{apsrev4-2}` suppresses the article title, which is mandatory.

Comment: In general the correct argument to `\bibliographystyle` should be the matching journal style, so one of `apsrev4-2`, `apsrmp4-2`, `aipnum4-2`, `aipauth4-2`, `aaprmrev4-2`.

Comment: @Mike would you mind if I edit your answer to cover the issue for the non-Phys Rev journals that REVTeX also supports?

Comment: @DaiBowen Sure.  Thanks!

Answer (score 12):

Indeed it's just a warning and you are expected to ignore it. You could make it go away by arranging for `SimpleTexNotes.bib` to contain control lines:

```
@CONTROL{REVTEX41Control}
@CONTROL{apsrev41Control,author="48",editor="1",pages="0",title="",year="1"}
```

instead of the `author="8"` line that was there previously. This explicitly activates `jnrlst` rather than having it set as a dependency. For example you could have your build process run `sed` over the `SimpleTexNotes.bib` before running bibtex. Using bibliographystyle causes revtex to not emit the `\citation{REVTEX41Control}` `\citation{apsrev41Control}` lines to the aux file, since non-revtex bst files will not understand these. In this particular case the revtex4-1.bst defaults to the correct settings equivalent to `@CONTROL{apsrev41Control,author="48",editor="1",pages="0",title="",year="1"}` as desired, but in other cases it may not do as you would want. For example adding the `longbibliography` option to the `\documentclass{revtex4-1}` line would have no effect.

Comment: Ah, I was trying all kinds of things in that `apsrev41Control` block, but couldn't come up with `author="48"`.  Thanks.  And thanks for the explanation, too!  Anyway, I think I'll just stick with the explicit `bibliographystyle` statement, as that is easiest to implement.

Comment: When I use either of the `@CONTROL` lines you wrote, I get a message `Repeated entry---line 1 of file references.bib`; The `@CONTROL` command is at line 1 of `references.bib`

Comment: @Girardi you need to edit those lines into `\jobname Notes.bib` (which is generated during TeXing of `\jobname.tex`) not in `references.bib`

Comment: ok, I found the Notes.bib file and added those two lines... But when I compile, it automatically changes the attributes to `author="00",editor="1",pages="1",title="0",year="0"` and gives `jnrlst` and `dotless` warnings