# Revtex4-1 warnings: "BibTeX jnrlst (dependency: not reversed) set 1" and "BibTeX I didn't find a database entry for X"

Tags: revtex

I'm using `revtex4-1` and I get these warnings: `BibTeX jnrlst (dependency: not reversed) set 1` and `BibTeX I didn't find a database entry for "nielsen"`.

**MWE:**

```
\documentclass[aps,twocolumn,nofootinbib,floatfix]{revtex4-1}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\begin{document}

What is Lorem Ipsum?

Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry \cite{nielsen}. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum. 

\begin{thebibliography}{25}
\bibitem{nielsen} M. A. Nielsen and I. L. Chuang, Quantum Computation and Quantum Information: 10th Anniversary Edition, 10th ed. (Cambridge  University Press, New York, NY, USA, 2011).
\end{thebibliography}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Note that [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/76056/167132) is not applicable to my situation as I'm not using any .bib file.

Any idea how to get rid of those warnings?

Comment: I do not get the warnings/errors you mention when I run the example. Do you maybe have old auxiliary files hanging about? Does the problem go away if you delete the `.aux` and `.bbl` files? Can you reproduce the issue when you run the shown example in an empty directory?

Comment: @moewe I don't see any auxiliary files. It's a standalone `.tex` file. I'm using Overleaf. You can view and edit the MWE [here](https://www.overleaf.com/7757948647dsxdccnmrcwj).

Comment: I can't be exactly sure but the quoted messages read as if they come from BibTeX directly (possibly the messages were filtered or otherwise processed by your editor), as you say yourself there is no need to run BibTeX on your file since you don't have a `.bib` file, it is possible that this is just the remnant of an earlier run.

Comment: Sorry I don't have an Overleaf account and the link requires a log-in. Try to clear the auxiliary files/cache (recompile from scratch): https://de.overleaf.com/learn/how-to/Clearing_the_cache, https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/447366/35864

Comment: Then I can't help you any more, sorry. I think internally Overleaf runs `latexmk` to make sure that the document is processed by all the right tools in the correct order. I tested the exact example you posted with my local install of `latexmk` and on the non-login version of Overleaf (v1): https://v1.overleaf.com/read/yzxqtkdbzqdb. As you can see the warnings do not occur. If they occur for you with the exact example posted the only explanation I can offer are left-over auxiliary files. If you cleared those and the error persists I'm out of ideas.

Comment: Perhaps related to https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/76028

Answer (score 18):

This error should disappear if you put `\bibliographystyle{apsrev4-1}` in the preamble, i.e. *before* `\begin{document}`.

(For `\documentclass{revtex4-2)`, use `\bibliographystyle{apsrev4-2}`.)

Comment: doing this removed the article titles from my bibliography! any way to get them back?

Comment: @ACarter if you review PRL papers, that's the expected behaviour.