# Error in preamble while compiling

Tags: preamble

I am getting errors while compiling my files, but the errors are not mentioning the line numbers where I can check and correct them. Can someone tell me what are these errors about?

```
enter code here
```

**Error:**

```
Package transparent Warning: Loading aborted, because pdfTeX is not running in PDF mode.

‪/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/transparent/transparent.sty‬
Package caption Warning: Unknown document class (or package), standard defaults will be used. See the caption package documentation for explanation.
 
‪/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/caption/caption.sty‬
Unused global option(s):
```

**My preamble looks like this:**

```
\documentclass[
superscriptaddress,
aps,border=5cm, article
]{revtex4-2}


%\usepackage[preprint]{nips_2018}  % so I can compile without the nips format
\usepackage{natbib} % this is probably into you nips_2018 format file
\usepackage{tikz}

%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % allow utf-8 input
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}    % use 8-bit T1 fonts
\usepackage{url}            % simple URL typesetting

\usepackage{mathtools,amsmath}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{adjustbox}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{epsf}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{stmaryrd}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{enumerate}

\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{footnote}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{scalefnt}

\usepackage{xfrac}
\usepackage{transparent}
\usepackage{rotate}

\usepackage{tabu}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{bm}

\usepackage[margin=25mm]{geometry}   % for setting page layout

\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage[font=small]{subcaption}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}

%\documentclass{scrbook} 
\usepackage{pst-func}
\psset{xunit=0.25,yunit=5}

\newcommand{\ve}[1]{\bm{#1}}

\newcommand{\ba}{\ve{a}}
\newcommand{\bb}{\ve{b}}
\newcommand{\bu}{\ve{u}}
\newcommand{\bv}{\ve{v}}
\newcommand{\br}{\ve{r}}
\newcommand{\bp}{\ve{p}}
\newcommand{\bt}{\ve{t}}
\newcommand{\bn}{\ve{n}}
\newcommand{\bc}{\ve{c}}
\newcommand{\bq}{\ve{q}}
\newcommand{\bff}{\ve{f}}
\newcommand{\bw}{\ve{w}}
\newcommand{\by}{\ve{y}}
\newcommand{\be}{\ve{e}}
\newcommand{\bg}{\ve{g}}
\newcommand{\bs}{\ve{s}}
\newcommand{\bx}{\ve{x}}

\newcommand{\bA}{\ve{A}}
\newcommand{\bS}{\ve{S}}
\newcommand{\bB}{\ve{B}}
\newcommand{\bU}{\ve{U}}
\newcommand{\bV}{\ve{V}}
\newcommand{\bQ}{\ve{Q}}
\newcommand{\bP}{\ve{P}}
\newcommand{\bGG}{\ve{G}}
\newcommand{\bRR}{\ve{R}}
\newcommand{\bX}{\ve{X}}
\newcommand{\bC}{\ve{C}}
\newcommand{\bF}{\ve{F}}
\newcommand{\bI}{\ve{I}}

\newcommand{\ddd}{\dd R \dd \dot{R}}
\newcommand{\bbE}{\mathbb{E}}
\newcommand{\Rdot}{\dot{R}}
\newcommand{\Rddot}{\ddot{R}}

\newcommand{\muR}{\mu_R}
\newcommand{\muRdot}{\mu_{\dot{R}}}
\newcommand{\sigmaR}{\sigma_R}
\newcommand{\sigmaRdot}{\sigma_{\dot{R}}}

\newcommand{\bmu}{\vec{\boldsymbol{\mu}}}
\newcommand{\btheta}{\vec{\boldsymbol{\theta}}}

\newcommand{\bLambda}{\boldsymbol{\Lambda}}
\newcommand{\blambda}{\boldsymbol{\lambda}}
\newcommand{\bSigma}{\boldsymbol{\Sigma}}
\newcommand{\bEps}{\boldsymbol{\varepsilon}}
\newcommand{\beps}{\boldsymbol{\varepsilon}}
%\newcommand{\bmu}{\boldsymbol{\mu}}
\newcommand{\balpha}{\boldsymbol{\alpha}}
\newcommand{\heps}{\hat{\varepsilon}}
\newcommand{\bdelta}{\boldsymbol{\delta}}
\newcommand{\vblambda}{\vec{\boldsymbol{\lambda}}}
\newcommand{\vbsigma}{\vec{\boldsymbol{\sigma}}}
\newcommand{\vbEps}{\vec{\boldsymbol{\varepsilon}}}
\newcommand{\vbdelta}{\vec{\boldsymbol{\delta}}}
\newcommand{\eps}{\varepsilon}

\newcommand{\vba}{\vec{\ve{a}}}
\newcommand{\vbu}{\vec{\ve{u}}}
\newcommand{\vbx}{\vec{\ve{x}}}
\newcommand{\vbv}{\vec{\ve{v}}}
\newcommand{\vbh}{\vec{\ve{h}}}
\newcommand{\vbbh}{\vec{\bar{\ve{h}}}}
\newcommand{\vbs}{\vec{\ve{s}}}
\newcommand{\vbf}{\vec{\ve{f}}}
\newcommand{\vq}{\vec{q}}

\newcommand{\hbx}{\hat{\ve{x}}}
\newcommand{\hby}{\hat{\ve{y}}}
\newcommand{\hbz}{\hat{\ve{z}}}

\newcommand{\tx}{\widetilde{\ve{x}}}
\newcommand{\tbB}{\widetilde{\ve{B}}}

\newcommand{\mom}{\mu'}
\newcommand{\bmom}{\vec{\boldsymbol{\mu}}'}
\newcommand{\Rt}{R}
\newcommand{\hR}{\hat{R}}

\newcommand{\dd}{\text{d}}
\newcommand{\gdot}{\dot\gamma}
\newcommand\Rey{\mbox{\text{Re}}}  % Reynolds number
\newcommand\Ca{\mbox{\text{Ca}}} % Cavitation number
\newcommand{\overbar}[1]{\mkern 1.5mu\overline{\mkern-1.5mu#1\mkern-1.5mu}\mkern 1.5mu}


% Making colors nice

\definecolor{lightblue}{rgb}{0.63, 0.74, 0.78}
\definecolor{seagreen}{rgb}{0.18, 0.42, 0.41}
\definecolor{orange}{rgb}{0.85, 0.55, 0.13}
\definecolor{silver}{rgb}{0.69, 0.67, 0.66}
\definecolor{rust}{rgb}{0.72, 0.26, 0.06}

\colorlet{lightsilver}{silver!30!white}
\colorlet{darkorange}{orange!75!black}
\colorlet{darksilver}{silver!65!black}
\colorlet{darklightblue}{lightblue!65!black}
\colorlet{darkrust}{rust!85!black}

\usepackage[colorlinks=true,linkcolor=darkrust,citecolor=darklightblue,urlcolor=darksilver]{hyperref}

\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}



\usepackage[strict]{changepage} % < added

\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,
                calc, chains,
                quotes}  % added
```

Comment: Are all of these packages needed for this document, or are you copying a preamble from document to document? I only ask as towards the end of the `\usepackage`  lines there is a commented out `%\documentclass{scrbook}`, which looks like a copy/paste thing.

Comment: @enkorvaks Whenever I see a section of document or answer on tex-stack which is of my use, I usually copy the packages on to my preamble and the rest to my main. So the preamble is original but has a lot of additions which I make time and again.

Comment: it's a really bad idea to add packages you don't use, it is much better to have an empty one and just add as needed otherwise you get issues like you show here `\usepackage{epsf}` shouldn't be in any document written after 1994 do you really use this.  `\usepackage{transparent}` causes the warning you show as it can't be used with latex, needs pdflatex, you can't use pdflatex as you have `\usepackage{pst-func}`   `[
superscriptaddress,
aps,border=5cm, article
]` are not revtex options so you get the option warning, `\usepackage{tabu}` is unmaintained and does not  work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Overleaf, I get three warnings (not errors):

1. Package caption Warning: Unknown document class (or package), standard defaults will be used. See the caption package documentation for explanation.
2. Unused global option(s):
3. jnrlst (dependency: not reversed) set 1

The caption warning is referring you to the [documentation](https://ctan.org/pkg/caption?lang=en).  But it's also plain enough to read: (sub)caption isn't familiar with revtex4-2, and isn't making any guarantees about what will happen.  (You can also cut out everything else in your preamble to verify that's the problem.)  If you don't need the subcaption package, then take it out.  If you do need to use it, then you'll need to ignore the warning, or tell TeX to ignore the warning.

Expanding the "Raw logs", we find that the unused global options are "border" and "article".  Taking them out of the `\documentclass[options]` removes that warning.

For jnrlst, a web search for that string leads to https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/567691/107497, which says to add `\bibliographystyle{apsrev4-2}` to your preamble.

I will echo enkorvaks's comment that this appears to be a preamble that you've copied over (the two packages that have been `% added` at the end also point to that).  If a copied preamble is giving you problems, are you sure you want to use it?